# where the derived table at? (using mysql 5.7)

Tags: mysql

so based on this article `https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-optimize-mysql-queries-for-speed-and-perfor`
i tried to make an index to optimize the speed of my query (because it takes 87 sec to executed this query)

```
 EXPLAIN SELECT 

gdStudioTbl.orderDate AS tanggalPesanan,
gdStudioTbl.orderDay AS hari,
gdStudioTbl.orderHour AS jam,
gdStudioTbl.orderMinute AS menit,
gdStudioTbl.orderNumbers AS nomorPesanan,
gdStudioTbl.productId AS idProduk,
gdStudioTbl.productName AS namaProduk,
gdStudioTbl.packNumber AS kemasan,
gdStudioTbl.orderWeight AS berat,
gdStudioTbl.orderPrice AS hargaTotal,
gdStudioTbl.yesterdayPackNumber AS kemasanKemarin,
gdStudioTbl.yesterdayOrderPrice AS hargaTotalKemarin,
gdStudioTbl.buyerId AS idPembeli,
gdStudioTbl.buyerName AS namaPembeli,
gdStudioTbl.buyerStatus AS statusPembeli,
gdStudioTbl.repeatBuyerStatus AS statusPembeliUlang,
gdStudioTbl.newBuyerStatus AS statusPembeliBaru,
CASE

WHEN (uniqueBuyerTbl.buyerId IS NOT NULL AND gdStudioTbl.repeatBuyerStatus = 1)
THEN 1
ELSE 0

END AS unikPembeliUlang,
CASE

WHEN (uniqueBuyerTbl.buyerId IS NOT NULL AND gdStudioTbl.newBuyerStatus = 1)
THEN 1
ELSE 0

END AS unikPembeliBaru,
gdStudioTbl.email AS email,
gdStudioTbl.profilePhone AS nomorTeleponProfil,
gdStudioTbl.recipientPhone AS nomorTeleponPenerima,
gdStudioTbl.deviceName AS tipeAlat,
gdStudioTbl.paymentMethod AS caraPembayaran,
gdStudioTbl.regencies AS daerah,
tbl12.tblCtgName12 AS kategori
FROM
(

SELECT

om.createdAt AS orderDateSort,

DATE_FORMAT(om.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d') AS orderDate,

DATE_FORMAT(om.createdAt, '%W') AS orderDay,

DATE_FORMAT(om.createdAt, '%H') AS orderHour,

DATE_FORMAT(om.createdAt, '%i') AS orderMinute,

om.code_order AS orderNumbers,

omd.product_id AS productId,

prd.name AS productName,

ROUND((omd.quantity / pck.pack_size), 2) AS packNumber,

ROUND((pck.pack_weight * ROUND((omd.quantity / pck.pack_size), 2)), 2) AS orderWeight,

ROUND((omd.price * omd.quantity), 2) AS orderPrice,
IFNULL(deltaTransactionTbl.packNumber, 0) AS yesterdayPackNumber,
IFNULL(deltaTransactionTbl.orderPrice, 0) AS yesterdayOrderPrice,

ob.buyer_id AS buyerId,

usr.fullname AS buyerName,

CASE

WHEN pbrTbl.buyerId IS NULL

THEN 'Ulang'

ELSE 'Baru'

END AS buyerStatus,

CASE

WHEN pbrTbl.buyerId IS NULL

THEN 1

ELSE 0

END AS repeatBuyerStatus,

CASE

WHEN pbrTbl.buyerId IS NOT NULL

THEN 1

ELSE 0

END AS newBuyerStatus,

usr.email AS email,

IFNULL(usr.mobile, '') AS profilePhone,

IFNULL(od.recipient_contact, '') AS recipientPhone,

dvc.name AS deviceName,

pmh.payment_name AS paymentMethod,

awb.customer_regency AS regencies

FROM air_way_bills awb

LEFT JOIN order_match om ON om.code_order = awb.code_order

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd ON omd.order_match_id = om.id

LEFT JOIN product prd ON prd.id = omd.product_id

LEFT JOIN packs pck ON pck.id = omd.pack_id

LEFT JOIN order_buyer ob ON ob.id = om.order_buyer_id

LEFT JOIN users usr ON usr.id = ob.buyer_id

LEFT JOIN

(

SELECT ob2.buyer_id AS buyerId

FROM order_match om2

LEFT JOIN order_buyer ob2 ON ob2.id = om2.order_buyer_id

WHERE om2.createdAt >= '2017-05-01 19:00:00'

AND om2.createdAt <= NOW()

AND om2.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

GROUP BY ob2.buyer_id
HAVING COUNT(ob2.buyer_id) = 1

) pbrTbl ON pbrTbl.buyerId = ob.buyer_id

LEFT JOIN order_delivery od ON od.order_match_id = om.id

LEFT JOIN devices dvc ON dvc.id = om.device_id

LEFT JOIN payment_method_history pmh ON pmh.order_match_id = om.id

LEFT JOIN

(

SELECT

omd4.product_id AS productId,

DATE_FORMAT(om4.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d') AS orderDate,
(SUM(ROUND((omd4.quantity / pck4.pack_size), 2)) / tomorrowOrderNumberTbl.orderNumber) AS packNumber,
(SUM(ROUND((omd4.price * omd4.quantity), 2)) / tomorrowOrderNumberTbl.orderNumber) AS orderPrice

FROM order_match om4

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd4 ON omd4.order_match_id = om4.id
LEFT JOIN packs pck4 ON pck4.id = omd4.pack_id
LEFT JOIN
(

SELECT

COUNT(om5.id) AS orderNumber,
omd5.product_id AS productId,
DATE_FORMAT(om5.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d') AS orderDate

FROM order_match om5

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd5 ON omd5.order_match_id = om5.id

WHERE om5.createdAt >= '2017-05-01 19:00:00'

AND om5.createdAt <= NOW()

AND om5.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

GROUP BY

omd5.product_id,

orderDate
) tomorrowOrderNumberTbl ON tomorrowOrderNumberTbl.productId = omd4.product_id
AND tomorrowOrderNumberTbl.orderDate = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(om4.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y/%m/%d')

WHERE om4.createdAt >= DATE_SUB('2017-05-01 19:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)

AND om4.createdAt <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

AND om4.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

GROUP BY

omd4.product_id,

DATE_FORMAT(om4.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d'),
tomorrowOrderNumberTbl.orderNumber

ORDER BY

omd4.product_id ASC,

orderDate ASC

) deltaTransactionTbl ON deltaTransactionTbl.productId = omd.product_id

AND deltaTransactionTbl.orderDate = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(om.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y/%m/%d')

WHERE om.createdAt >= '2017-05-01 19:00:00'

AND om.createdAt <= NOW()

AND om.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)
UNION ALL

SELECT

DATE_ADD(om6.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS orderDateSort,

DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(om6.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y/%m/%d') AS orderDate,

DATE_FORMAT(om6.createdAt, '%W') AS yesterdayOrderDay,

DATE_FORMAT(om6.createdAt, '%H') AS yesterdayOrderHour,

DATE_FORMAT(om6.createdAt, '%i') AS yesterdayOrderMinute,

om6.code_order AS yesterdayOrderNumbers,

omd6.product_id AS yesterdayProductId,

prd6.name AS yesterdayProductName,

0 AS packNumber,

0 AS orderWeight,

0 AS orderPrice,

ROUND((omd6.quantity / pck6.pack_size), 2) AS yesterdayPackNumber,

ROUND((omd6.price * omd6.quantity), 2) AS yesterdayOrderPrice,

ob6.buyer_id AS buyerId,

usr6.fullname AS buyerName,

CASE

WHEN pbrTbl2.buyerId IS NULL

THEN 'Ulang'

ELSE 'Baru'

END AS buyerStatus,

CASE

WHEN pbrTbl2.buyerId IS NULL

THEN 1

ELSE 0

END AS repeatBuyerStatus,

CASE

WHEN pbrTbl2.buyerId IS NOT NULL

THEN 1

ELSE 0

END AS newBuyerStatus,

usr6.email AS email,

IFNULL(usr6.mobile, '') AS profilePhone,

IFNULL(od6.recipient_contact, '') AS recipientPhone,

dvc6.name AS deviceName,

pmh6.payment_name AS paymentMethod,

awb6.customer_regency AS regencies

FROM air_way_bills awb6

LEFT JOIN order_match om6 ON om6.code_order = awb6.code_order

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd6 ON omd6.order_match_id = om6.id

LEFT JOIN product prd6 ON prd6.id = omd6.product_id

LEFT JOIN packs pck6 ON pck6.id = omd6.pack_id

LEFT JOIN order_buyer ob6 ON ob6.id = om6.order_buyer_id

LEFT JOIN users usr6 ON usr6.id = ob6.buyer_id

LEFT JOIN order_delivery od6 ON od6.order_match_id = om6.id

LEFT JOIN devices dvc6 ON dvc6.id = om6.device_id

LEFT JOIN payment_method_history pmh6 ON pmh6.order_match_id = om6.id

LEFT JOIN

(

SELECT

DATE_FORMAT(om7.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d') AS orderDate,

omd7.product_id AS productId

FROM order_match om7

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd7 ON omd7.order_match_id = om7.id

WHERE om7.createdAt >= '2017-05-01 19:00:00'

AND om7.createdAt <= NOW()

AND om7.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

GROUP BY

orderDate,

omd7.product_id

ORDER BY

orderDate DESC,

omd7.product_id ASC

) orderTbl ON orderTbl.orderDate = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(om6.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y/%m/%d')

AND orderTbl.productId = omd6.product_id

LEFT JOIN

(

SELECT ob8.buyer_id AS buyerId

FROM order_match om8

LEFT JOIN order_buyer ob8 ON ob8.id = om8.order_buyer_id

WHERE om8.createdAt >= '2017-05-01 19:00:00'

AND om8.createdAt <= NOW()

AND om8.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

GROUP BY ob8.buyer_id

HAVING COUNT(ob8.buyer_id) = 1

) pbrTbl2 ON pbrTbl2.buyerId = ob6.buyer_id

WHERE om6.createdAt >= DATE_SUB('2017-05-01 19:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)

AND om6.createdAt <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

AND om6.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

AND orderTbl.productId IS NULL

GROUP BY

DATE_FORMAT(om6.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d'),

DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(om6.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y/%m/%d'),

DATE_FORMAT(om6.createdAt, '%W'),

DATE_FORMAT(om6.createdAt, '%H'),

DATE_FORMAT(om6.createdAt, '%i'),

om6.code_order,

omd6.product_id,

yesterdayPackNumber,

yesterdayOrderPrice,

awb6.customer_regency
) gdStudioTbl
LEFT JOIN
(

SELECT

groupedBuyerTbl.orderDateSort AS orderDateSort,

MIN(groupedBuyerTbl.productId) AS productId,

groupedBuyerTbl.buyerId AS buyerId

FROM

(

SELECT

om9.createdAt AS orderDateSort,

omd9.product_id AS productId,

ob9.buyer_id AS buyerId

FROM air_way_bills awb9

LEFT JOIN order_match om9 ON om9.code_order = awb9.code_order

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd9 ON omd9.order_match_id = om9.id

LEFT JOIN order_buyer ob9 ON ob9.id = om9.order_buyer_id

WHERE om9.createdAt >= '2017-05-01 19:00:00'

AND om9.createdAt <= NOW()

AND om9.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

UNION ALL

SELECT

DATE_ADD(om10.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS orderDateSort,

omd10.product_id AS yesterdayProductId,

ob10.buyer_id AS buyerId

FROM air_way_bills awb10

LEFT JOIN order_match om10 ON om10.code_order = awb10.code_order

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd10 ON omd10.order_match_id = om10.id

LEFT JOIN packs pck10 ON pck10.id = omd10.pack_id

LEFT JOIN order_buyer ob10 ON ob10.id = om10.order_buyer_id

LEFT JOIN

(

SELECT

DATE_FORMAT(om11.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d') AS orderDate,

omd11.product_id AS productId

FROM order_match om11

LEFT JOIN order_match_detail omd11 ON omd11.order_match_id = om11.id

WHERE om11.createdAt >= '2017-05-01 19:00:00'

AND om11.createdAt <= NOW()

AND om11.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

GROUP BY

orderDate,

omd11.product_id

ORDER BY

orderDate DESC,

omd11.product_id ASC

) orderTbl ON orderTbl.orderDate = DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(om10.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y/%m/%d')

AND orderTbl.productId = omd10.product_id

WHERE om10.createdAt >= DATE_SUB('2017-05-01 19:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)

AND om10.createdAt <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

AND om10.order_status_id IN (4, 5, 6)

AND orderTbl.productId IS NULL

GROUP BY

DATE_FORMAT(om10.createdAt, '%Y/%m/%d'),

DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(om10.createdAt, INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y/%m/%d'),

DATE_FORMAT(om10.createdAt, '%W'),

DATE_FORMAT(om10.createdAt, '%H'),

DATE_FORMAT(om10.createdAt, '%i'),

om10.code_order,

omd10.product_id,

ROUND((omd10.quantity / pck10.pack_size), 2),

ROUND((omd10.price * omd10.quantity), 2)

) groupedBuyerTbl

GROUP BY

groupedBuyerTbl.orderDateSort,

groupedBuyerTbl.buyerId
) uniqueBuyerTbl ON uniqueBuyerTbl.orderDateSort = gdStudioTbl.orderDateSort
AND uniqueBuyerTbl.productId = gdStudioTbl.productId
AND uniqueBuyerTbl.buyerId = gdStudioTbl.buyerId
LEFT JOIN
(

SELECT

prdc12.product_id AS prdcProductId12,
tbl13.ctgName13 AS tblCtgName12

FROM product_categories prdc12

INNER JOIN

(

SELECT

ctg13.id AS ctgId13,
ctg13.name AS ctgName13

FROM categories ctg13

WHERE ctg13.main_categories = 1

AND ctg13.status = 1

AND ctg13.show_in_reports = 1

) tbl13 ON tbl13.ctgId13 = prdc12.category_id
) tbl12 ON tbl12.prdcProductId12 = gdStudioTbl.productId
ORDER BY

gdStudioTbl.orderDateSort DESC,
gdStudioTbl.productId ASC
```

and the results was like this

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |    table    | partitions | type  |                     possible_keys                     | key  | key_len | ref  |   rows   | filtered |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>  | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                                  | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 72592704 |      100 | Using filesort                               |
|  9 | DERIVED     | <derived10> | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                                  | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  3041440 |      100 | Using temporary; Using filesort              |
| 10 | DERIVED     | awb9        | NULL       | index | NULL                                                  | awb4 | 5       | NULL |   170135 |      100 | Using index                                  |
| 11 | UNION       | awb10       | NULL       | index | NULL                                                  | awb4 | 5       | NULL |   170135 |      100 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 12 | DERIVED     | om11        | NULL       | ALL   | fk_order_status_id_order_match_order_status,createdat | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   190432 |    26.18 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | awb         | NULL       | ALL   | NULL                                                  | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   170135 |      100 | NULL                                         |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

my questions is, where's the table **derived2**, **derived10**, and any others table who appear in that, so i can made an index from that table and can make the row to become more less than that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derived is a temporary table created possibly for your inline views in the query thats created, here  `derived10` is referring to id =10 calculations and `derived2` is referring to id=2 Derived tables in explain plan output, if you see the 'table' in explain plan output `awb (derived2)` **air_way_bills** in first inline view and `awb9 (derived10)` again the **air_way_bills** in later part of query, you have to check the inline views in your query which are referencing this tables and fine tune it.

quick tip:- seeing your explain plan there are lot of full table scan going on you should design the index properly for the same and avoid not needed clause or unwanted conversions or unwanted sorting in the query, first step is to remove not wanted elements in the query and create index on the columns in where clause and see if it improves your query performance.

Here im adding the link to reference for in dept details

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html

Comment: im sorry im new in derived table, so based on my query, which part query are in derived 2 and derived 10?

Comment: If you follow explain plan you have table name specified as awb and awb9, follow the ids, then go back and check on query where these tables are possibly referenced, there you should tune the query.

Comment: quick tip:- seeing your explain plan there are lot of full table scan going on you should design the index properly for the same and avoid not needed clause or conversions and unwanted sorting in the query.

Comment: so my plan is going to take analyze the queries in derived 2 and derived 10 so the row who tracking can be more less, but i cant find the query inside the derived 2 because idk where derived 2 table at

Comment: Where ever in explain plan output the 'type' column you see 'ALL' you should go back and analyse the query there and try creating index for the columns referenced in 'Where' clause at first and see if your query time improves. In general you should really analyse the query and remove the Unwanted stuff this is first step.

Comment: yes i understand, my problem is, idk where derived table 2 at and cant analyze it because i dont know where "derived2" start and end

Comment: im sorry, can you just explain where my "derived2" table at

Comment: oh i see, so i must take a look at table awb and awb9 because it's linked in derived2 and derived10?

Comment: Yes, since you asked specifically that, but general avoid using lot of inline views, i think you should restructure the query a bit and create some indexes on where clause.

Comment: so after i take a look at my queries, lets say awb10 and awb09 are same tables but in the process, using different coloumn, what if i put all of the coloumn in table awb to make it index, is it okay?

Comment: Designing index is an art, for more details i would recommend you go through this sildes, it really helps ! https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really